# How to access a variable in an EJS file from a different JS file

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am building a simple web app that takes in 3 different types of inputs and renders one of 3 different EJS file from a views directory (using Node and Express). Each of the rendered EJS files needs the contents of a static array. The static array is big and I want to store it in a separate JS file. I tried putting this code in the EJS files:

app.js

```
var arrayFile = require('./arrayFile.js');

app.get("/", async function(req, res){
    let blockVariable = await request({
       method: "get",
       uri: "https://testardor.jelurida.com/nxt?requestType=getBlocks",
       json: true
    });

    var blocks2 = []
    blockVariable.blocks.forEach(function(element){
        if (element.transactions.length != 0){
            blocks2.push(element);
        }
    });

    res.render("home", {blocks: blockVariable.blocks,
                        blocks2: blocks2,
                        arrayFile: arrayFile
    });
});
```

home.ejs

```
<%= arrayFile %>
```

arrayFile.js

```
array = [{thing1: 1}, {thing2: 2}]
```

This gives results [object Object] on the home.ejs page

I tried making home.ejs

```
<%= JSON.stringify(arrayFile) %>
```

with results {}

Comment: you need to show contents of `arrayFile.js` probably omitting the array contents leaving few objects for demo. also your template and express route.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are mixing contexts. `<script src="arrayFile.js"></script>` will work on browser side. While `<%= array %>` works on server side. So it should be something like this, just to give you idea:

```
// assuming that your array is exported as default
var array = require('./arrayFile.js');
app.get('/page', (req, res) => {
  // make array available to EJS context
  res.render('page_ejs', {array});
});
```

But this will probably generate one big `HTML` with imprinted array. Which is not what you probably may want, because then you don't actually need `<script src="arrayFile.js"></script>` in your EJS.

If you want to files to be shipped to browser, your `HTML` and `arrayFile.js`, then you will have to properly export array in `arrayFile.js` so that you can write something like:

```
// this will be fetched by browser
<script src="arrayFile.js"></script>
// and then executed by browser
<script>
  console.log(yourArray);
</script>
```

Then you don't need `<%= array %>` in your EJS.

Of course, you can mix both ways, making array available to EJS, and also to the browser.